# How to host ethereum dapp directly on Cpanel server?

Tags: node.js, cpanel

Is it possible for me to host an ethereum dapp frontend directly on cpanel?

If yes how do i install the necessary packages for it directly on cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what tool you develop your dapp.

If you develop with nodejs and some frontend framework, you can simply setting domain to file server and upload webpack compiled files to the directory.

If you develop in another language, you need to install the application and upload files.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response. Please kindly link me to where i can get the webpack to upload on the server. Thanks